# I want to check if a string like A B C D exists in each cell of its corresponding row or not. If it does not exists then NA should be returned

Tags: r

I have put the data and output here. In first row if anything is not A,B,C or D then it should return NA , in second row if anything is not A,C,B or E then return NA

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a example showing one option to make it

```
> t(mapply(function(a, b) b[match(a, b)], asplit(x, 1), strsplit(y, "")))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] NA   "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] NA   "B"  "C"  NA
```

## Data

```
> x <- rbind(c("E", "B", "C", "A"), c("S", "B", "C", "D"))

> y <- c("ABCD", "ACBE")

> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "E"  "B"  "C"  "A"
[2,] "S"  "B"  "C"  "D"

> y
[1] "ABCD" "ACBE"
```